# So can a class have two default constructors?

Tags: c++

I'm reading my book and it says "A constructor that supplies default arguments for all its parameters also defines the default constructor"

so in the following code:

```
class Book {

    public: 

    int pages = 25;
    double price = 10.0;
    std::string font = "Times New Roman";

    Book() {}
    Book(int n, double p, std::string f): pages(n), price(p), font(f) { }
};
```

Both the constructor that takes no parameters and the constructor that supplies default arguments for its parameters are default constructors? Or by default arguments does it mean that the second constructor would need to look something like: Book(): pages(5), price(46), font("Times New Roman") {}

Comment: Default arguments means something like `Book(int n = 0, double p = 0.0 ... etc.` so your second constructor would *not* be a default ctor.

Comment: "also defines the default constructor" is supposed to mean "can also be used to define the default constructor". It is not intended to suggest that you can meaningfully have two default constructors.

Comment: @PeteBecker I wonder if the wording in the standard is actually wrong. It says "the default constructor", not "a default constructor (candidate)". Would that mean that the answer I gave should be rejected by a standard conforming compiler? Or should the wording be clarified as there is no such thing as "the" default constructor?

Comment: @DanielFrey - what wording are you referring to? [class.ctor]/5 says "A _default_ constructor for a class X is a constructor of class X that can be called without an argument."

Comment: @PeteBecker Examples are 3.1/3 (only a note), 8.5/7, 8.5/8 also *suggests* that only one can exist, 12/1 right at the beginning...

Answer (score 5):

The funny thing is that your class *can* have multiple constructor overload which could work with no arguments and are therefore valid default constructors:

```
struct A
{
    A() {}
    A( int i = 0 ) {}
};
```

This is perfectly legal to write. The answer to the question from the title is therefore: **Yes.** The only problem is that you can not use them - they are ambiguous. When you write:

```
A a;
```

you get an error as both would match.

Answer (score 3):

If you can construct your object without calling a constructor explicitly<sup>*</sup>, then you have a *default* constructor. A class has a default constructor:

- If you don't create any constructor. ( `= default`)
- If you create a constructor without any argument.
- If you create a constructor which all its arguments have default values.

---

<sup>*</sup> To clear the statement, you must have the ability to make an object like below:

```
Book book;
```

Comment: @clcto: That's not a default constructor. That's a one-argument constructor. The difference is that a default constructor is used when *default-initializing* an instance. Default-initialization is what happens when you just declare the instance variable and don't give it anything.

Comment: @M M. in my example, is there a difference between writing Book() {} and between writing Book() = default; 
? It seems to have the same effect, but my book says that if there is another constructor then I should use =default.

Comment: @FrostyStraw: No difference. I'm not sure about the statement of that book.

Comment: @M M. so is there any particular reason as to why it says I should use =default?

Comment: My book says: 

Sales_data() = default;
First, note that this construct defines the default constructor because it takes no arguments. We are defining this constructor only because we want to provide other constructors as well as the default constructor...Under the new standard, if we want the default behavior, we can ask the compiler to generate the constructor for us by writing =default after that parameter list"

Answer (score 1):

> A constructor that supplies default arguments for all its parameters also defines the default constructor

This means using default parameters. In your example this means:

```
Book( int n = 5, double p = 46, std::string f = "Times New Roman" ) :
    pages( n ),
    price( p ),
    font( f ) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are taking about types of constructor. So there are three,  default constructor by complier, default constructor by programmer with default arguments, and default constructor by programmer without dafault arguments. So you are talking about about 2nd type. Yes, it is a type of default construct